# Add checked boxed values from CheckBox widget to a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, listview, checkbox

I'm building a dialog which allow user to use multi Regions by checking the checkBox next to the region name.

what I wanna know is how to add the Checkbox checked values to a list of int to be sent later to the API

And how to make multi select which not affect the value of the others check boxes , What I mean is if I checked the box the whole list stays unchecked

please I've been trying for a long time and got nothing

[image]

```
                                        showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (context) {
                                            return AlertDialog(
                                              content: Column(
                                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                children: [
                                                  Text('يرجي اختيار المناطق',
                                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                      style: mediumStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 21,
                                                          color: AppColors.blackColor)),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 20.h,
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    width: 500,
                                                    height: 250,
                                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                                      itemCount: state.selectedCity!.regions.length,
                                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                       bool isChecked = false;
                                                        return CheckboxListTile(
                                                          title: Text(
                                                            state.selectedCity!.regions[index].name,
                                                            style: mediumStyle(fontSize: 20.sp, color: AppColors.blackColor),
                                                          ),
                                                          value: isChecked,
                                                          onChanged: (value) {
                                                            setState(() => isChecked = value!);
                                                            List regions = [];

                                                          },
                                                        );
                                                      },
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            );
```

Comment: could you add your full code of your dialog?

Comment: code is posted..

Comment: thanks, now that is clear  your not using another class for your dialog, could you add the full code of your main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String, bool> selectedRegions = {};
     state.selectedCity!.regions.for(region){
      selectedRegions[region.name]=false;
     }


showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (context) {
                                        return AlertDialog(
                                          content: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            children: [
                                              Text('يرجي اختيار المناطق',
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  style: mediumStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 21,
                                                      color: AppColors.blackColor)),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 20.h,
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 500,
                                                height: 250,
                                                child: ListView(
        children: selectedRegions.keys.map((String key) {
          return new CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(key,
            style: mediumStyle(fontSize: 20.sp, color: AppColors.blackColor),),
            value: selectedRegions[key],
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedRegions[key] = value;
              });
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
                                        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, using your variables:

```dart
Future<void> showADialog(List<String> items) async {
    final selectedIndexes = <int>[];
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'يرجي اختيار المناطق',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 500,
                  height: 250,
                  child: StatefulBuilder(
                    builder: (context, setState) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: items.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final item = items[index];

                          return CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              item,
                            ),
                            value: selectedIndexes.contains(index),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              if (value == null) return;
                              setState(() {
                                value
                                    ? selectedIndexes.add(index)
                                    : selectedIndexes.remove(index);
                              });
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
    print(selectedIndexes);
  }
```